# Xpath incompatible with Internet Explorer

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xpath, compatibility

I am trying to extract XML with XPath. It works well with Firefox and Chrome, but, it doesn't work with IE9. Is there some trick or a hack I should do? You can see it [here](http://faunea.com/xpath-A1.html).

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}

//xml=loadXMLDoc("productfeed-production-version_sample.xml");
xml=loadXMLDoc("data.xml");
//path="/Products/Product/Category"
path="root/article[3]/Price"
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
    var nodes=xml.selectNodes(path);

    for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
    {
        document.write(nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("<br>");
    }
}
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{
    var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    var result=nodes.iterateNext();

    while (result)
    {
        document.write(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("<br>");
        result=nodes.iterateNext();
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root>
<article>
    <title>Best of the West - Édition Été 2013</title>
    <description>Un voyage dans l'Ouest américain est sans aucun doute ce qu'il y a de mieux pour qui veut se rendre aux Etats-Unis! Vous y transiterez par trois des villes les plus branchées...</description>
    <url>http://www.connections.be</url>
    <urltext>Visit the Site: connections.be</urltext>
    <Price>199,99</Price>
</article>
<article>
    <title>Hôtel Yotel</title>
    <description>Prenez le concept des hôtels capsule japonais, ajoutez-y le meilleur de la première classe des avions, saupoudrez le tout avec un style urbain et tendance,...</description>
    <url>http://www.connections.be</url>
    <urltext>Learn more</urltext>
    <Price>199,99</Price>
</article>
<article>
    <title>Essential Thailand</title>
    <description>Ce programme individuel, idéal pour un premier voyage en Thaïlande, vous emmène à la découverte des points d'orgue de Bangkok et de Chiang Mai.</description>
    <url>http://www.connections.be</url>
    <urltext>Continue Reading...</urltext>
    <Price>199,99</Price>
</article>
</root>
```

Comment: What exactly happens with IE 9 when you say "it does not work"? I have IE 10 here and that says that the method `selectNodes` is not supported. I know how to fix that by ensuring the HTTP request is not done with `XMLHttpRequest` but with `new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0')` so that `responseXML` is an MSXML DOM document which supports XPath with `selectNodes` but I am currently not sure which problem you encounter with IE 9. So please provide some details on the error you get, if you get one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one of the following recommended XPath libraries in order for XPath to work in IE:

- <strike>[JavaScript-XPath](http://coderepos.org/share/wiki/JavaScript-XPath) (I use this one)</strike> **Update**: This is now defunct, an [archived version from late 2016](http://web.archive.org/web/20161024202858/http://coderepos.org/share/wiki/JavaScript-XPath) can be seen in the Internet Archive.
- [wicked-good-xpath](https://github.com/google/wicked-good-xpath) - This is a re-implementation JavaScript-XPath by Google, faster and with a smaller code size.
- [jquery-xpath](https://github.com/ilinsky/jquery-xpath) - A jQuery extension with XPath 2.0 support.

Good luck!